# React class component inside react hook - DOM not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have below composition:

```
const HookComponent = (props)=> {

    let [month, changeMonth] = useState(moment());


    return ( 
        <ChildComponent
            month={month}
            onChange={m => changeMonth(m)}
            minStep={5}
            prevMonthIcon="ion-ios-arrow-left"
            nextMonthIcon="ion-ios-arrow-right"
          />
    )
}
```

The ChildComponent is a class component which updates the month using setState. Problem with above is that the change is not reflecting on DOM but the state in parent component is changing (via user input - button which changes the state in ChildComponent). I logged it and confirm the month in parent is changing. Is this some limitation of react when using class components within hooks?

When I convert HookComponent to class component and change month using setState, it works as expected and DOM changes on input change.

Comment: Can you show the code for `ChildComponent`?

Comment: The child component is actually a calender class I am using from below git url: https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment/blob/master/src/input-moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `InputMoment` component does not use a `month` prop, but a `moment` one.

Also, it seems that `InputMoment` is returning the same moment instance that is passed as `moment` prop. This causes that when you execute the `changeMonth` statement, as the reference does not change, the element is not re-rendered.

You can solve this by storing an object in the state. When you call `changeMonth` you pass a new object, and the `InputMoment` is then re-rendered correctly:

```
const HookComponent = (props)=> {
    let [month, changeMonth] = useState({ m: moment() });

    return ( 
        <ChildComponent
            moment={month.m}
            onChange={m => changeMonth({ m })}
            minStep={5}
            prevMonthIcon="ion-ios-arrow-left"
            nextMonthIcon="ion-ios-arrow-right"
          />
    )
}
```